# UIImageView not changing after assignment

Tags: ios, uiimageview

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *itemImage;
```

assignment：

```
self.itemImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[item imageURL]];
NSLog(@"%@",[item imageURL]);
NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageNamed:[item imageURL]]);
NSLog(@"%@",self.itemImage.image);
```

result：

```
2016-08-29 19:17:10.491 Calibration[7349:2878944] /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C855E6A6-4787-4E96-9960-DA7BE37572BE/Documents/Q2ER004.png
2016-08-29 19:17:10.491 Calibration[7349:2878944] <UIImage: 0x150069d00> size {750, 560} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
2016-08-29 19:17:10.491 Calibration[7349:2878944] <UIImage: 0x150416c80> size {750, 560} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

After assignment the image doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.itemImage.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[item imageURL]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access an image stored within a certain directory on the device and not in an asset bundle try this:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imageURL];
```

Or, add the image to an asset bundle and access it using:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use IBOutlet that you need to reach it by _itemImage, then try this code below,

```
[_itemImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imageURL]];
```

You can also add the image into your project, then try this one,

```
[_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Q2ER004.png"]];
```